# how to debug EF 5 null reference exception?

Tags: entity-framework

I am getting a null refrence exception when im filtering EF but I am absolultely clueless.

[image]

```
public IEnumerable<TonalityBatchModel> GetTonalityBatch(int briefID)
{
    try
    {
        var brief = NeptuneUnitOfWork.Briefs.FindWhere(b => b.ID == briefID).FirstOrDefault();

        if (brief != null && brief.TonalityCriteria != null)
                    {
                        return brief.TonalityCriteria.TonalityBatches
                                    .Select(b => new TonalityBatchModel()
                                        {
                                            BriefID = b.BriefID,
                                            Status = b.TonalityCriteria.IsActive == true ?"Active":"Ended",
                                            BatchID = b.ID,
                                            CompetitorID = b.BriefCompetitorID,
                                            Competitor = brief.BriefCompetitors.Where(i=>i.ID == b.BriefCompetitorID).Select(c=>c.Organisation.Name).First(),
                                            Size = b.BatchSize,
                                            StartDate = b.StartDate,
                                            EndDate = b.EndDate,
                                            IsPublished = b.Lookup_TonalityBatchStatus.ID == (int)TonalityBatchStatus.Published?"Yes":"No",
                                            IsCompleted = b.Lookup_TonalityBatchStatus.ID == (int)TonalityBatchStatus.Completed ? "Yes" : "No",
                                            IsAssigned = b.Lookup_TonalityBatchStatus.ID == (int)TonalityBatchStatus.Allocated ? "Yes" : "No",
                                            ImportantCount = b.TonalityItems.Count(i=> i.IsImportant),
                                            ArticlesCount = b.TonalityItems.Count,
                                            FavourableCount = b.TonalityItems.Count(i => i.Lookup_TonalityScoreTypes.ID ==(int)TonalitySourceType.Favourable),
                                            UnfavourableCount = b.TonalityItems.Count(i => i.Lookup_TonalityScoreTypes.ID ==(int)TonalitySourceType.Unfavourable),
                                            NeutralCount = b.TonalityItems.Count(i => i.Lookup_TonalityScoreTypes.ID ==(int)TonalitySourceType.Neutral)

                                        }).ToList();
                    }

                    return new List<TonalityBatchModel>();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not a good question. First you would like to debug Linq library, not entity framework. Second - you just need to figure out what is null in this case. It's easier to figure this out without debugging entity framework or a system library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reduce your query to a simpler query, and then start building it back up again until the `NullReferenceException` occurs. Looking at your code, here are some likely places (I'm making some assumptions since I don't know everything about your model):

```
Competitor = brief.BriefCompetitors.Where(i=>i.ID == b.BriefCompetitorID).Select(c=>c.Organisation.Name).First()
```

`BriefCompetitors` could be null. `c.Organisation` could be null.

```
IsPublished = b.Lookup_TonalityBatchStatus.ID == (int)TonalityBatchStatus.Published?"Yes":"No",
```

(and other similar lines) `b.Lookup_TonalityBatchStatus` might be null.

```
ImportantCount = b.TonalityItems.Count(i=> i.IsImportant),
```

(and other similar lines) `b.TonalityItems` might be null.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your count is returning null records. I could be wrong but the SQL that's being produced here is something like:

```
INNER JOIN TonalityItems i on i.Lookup_TonalityScoreTypes == x
```

Where `x` is the value of `(int)TonalitySourceType.Favourable`. Because this join has no matching results there is nothing to do a `count` on. You could try adding `?? 0` to the end of the query:

```
FavourableCount = b.TonalityItems.Count(i => i.Lookup_TonalityScoreTypes.ID ==(int)TonalitySourceType.Favourable) ?? 0,
```

Comment: Count() on an empty set will return 0, not null and not an exception. However, if you call something line `a.b.SomeSet.Count()`, and `a.b.SomeSet` is null, you'll get a NullReferenceException.